# For loop, iterate and call

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing some code and have come across the following loop. Is there a more pythonic way of writing this.

```
# obj_list = list of tuples [(someint, object)...]
for a, obj in obj_list:
    obj.callable()
```

Comment: what is `a` and do you plan on using it? And do you want to store whatever `obj.callable()` returns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really, it looks fine. Instead of `a` you could use `_` which signifies that the value is not used, but that is a very minor point.

If `obj.callable()` were to return a value, and you wanted to store the values, you could use a list comprehension:

```
results = [obj.callable() for _, obj in obj_list]
```

`results` would contain a list of the values returned by each call to `obj.callable()`.

Comment: you could write it as `results = map(methodcaller('callable'), map(itemgetter(1), obj_list))` though the list comprehension is probably more preferrable in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. There might be "more pythonic" ways but they would sacrifice readability or do something slightly different.

E.g. you could you list comprehensions:

```
returns = [ x.callable() for dummy, x in obj_list]
```

But it looks almost exactly the same and stores results (might be undesirable).

You could use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#map), but function that takes out desired element of a tuple and calls a method on it, though possible, would probably look like an obfuscation.

Comment: `map()` is intended to apply the _same_ function to each item in an iterable, so yes, that would definitely be an obfuscation.

Comment: Just mentioning for the sake of completeness. It is possible and popped in my mind. It also would be the same function. Take tuple, take 0th element, call `callable` =). Definitely not the way to go for me. For the record I was writing at the same time as you, and I see we came with the same thing and overall judgment. There are probably few more ways, but they most probably are not better in any way.